# How to install the d3-rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I try to use the d3.js gem (https://github.com/iblue/d3-rails) but i have this rails error (rails 5.1.6):

```
couldn't find file 'd3' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /Users/.../app/assets/config
  /Users/.../app/assets/images
  /Users/.../app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/.../app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.6/lib/assets/compiled
  /Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.1.6/lib/assets/compiled
  /Users/.../code/agiret/project/caloo/node_modules
  /Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/javascripts
  /Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/fonts
  /Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/images
  /Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.7.0/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.7.0/assets/fonts
```

Someone may help me ?

Here, my /app/assets/javascripts/application.js :

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require d3
//= require_tree .
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try and restart the server?

Comment: Yes, thanks... it seems it was just that : restarting the server !
Anytime you install a `gem`, or touch sth in the `/config` folder, restart your `rails` server !

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server should do the trick.